# The NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) error

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to load a URL into a webview via the code below, everytime I try to loadRequest, it fails with the error above.

```
@IBOutlet weak var wb: UIWebView!
func openCheckoutPage(landingUrl:String,token:String)
{
        let url:String = "\(landingUrl)&token=\(token)"
        self.wb.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!))
}
```

Take in mind I have already added the appropriate NSAppTransportSecurity key(s) in my info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>walgreens.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that as part of loading that URL, we need to load other URLs that are *not* included under `walgreens.com`. But you have turned off arbitrary loads, so they can't load.

Comment: setting the key to true for NSAllowsArbitraryLoads still throws the error

Comment: Well maybe it's just a bad URL, bad server, whatever. I've no idea what your URL is or what's there. Have you tried it in Safari on the desktop?

Comment: The url loads fine on the desktop, the only error it shows is http://imgur.com/bdd95wR

Comment: Fascinating. Could that actually be the issue?

Comment: Maybe? I don't know thats why I asked haha